# DockerコンテナがホストOSのカーネルを使える理由をおしえて下さい

Tags: linux, windows, docker, macos

DockerとVMと何が違うのかを調べていたところ、VMはOSを含めて動作する一方でDockerコンテナはホストOSのカーネルを使うことができ、それ以外に必要となるライブラリやアプリがDockerコンテナに含まれるという風に把握しました。

そこでタイトルのような疑問が浮かんできました。
OSのカーネルはOSごとに違うはずです、ホストOSがWindowsでDockerコンテナ上でLinuxを動かす場合に、Windowsのカーネルを使ってLinuxを動かすということになります。
WindowsのカーネルでLinuxを動かすことができるのでしょうか？
これがどうしてこういうことができるのかをぐぐったのですが、答えが得られませんでした。

DockerコンテナがホストOSのカーネルを使える理由をおしえて下さい。
この質問の目的としては、DockerとVMの違いを把握することなので、
もしこの質問の意図がとんちんかんであれば、そちらを汲み取って案内いただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

> ホストOSがWindowsでDockerコンテナ上でLinuxを動かす場合に、Windowsのカーネルを使ってLinuxを動かすということになります。

「ホストOSがWindowsでDockerコンテナ上でLinuxを動かす場合」というのがDocker for Windowsを指すものと解釈して回答します。

Docker for Windowsはいまのところ、WindowsのHyper-VのVM上でLinuxを動かして、その中でLinuxのコンテナを動かすものです。Windowsのカーネルを使ってLinuxを動かすわけではありません。

Answer (score 1):

専門用語の詳細は忘れてしまっていますが、以下の通りだったと記憶しています。

Linux には、カーネルの部分をそのままに、実行されているプロセス環境・ファイルシステムをまるっといれかえて実行する、みたいな機能があったと記憶しています。それに、レイヤー型仮想ファイルシステムなど、いろいろなライブラリを付け加えていって完成するのが docker だったはずです。

docker はなので、 OS カーネルとして Linux の上でないと動作しません。 Linux のカーネル(とそれを含んだ OS) を動かすために、 docker for {Mac, Windows} は、 Linux VM を内部で動かしていたと記憶しています。

http://docs.docker.jp/engine/installation/mac.html

例えば、上記ページなどが、公式ドキュメントでこの周辺ツールがどう動作しているのか記述してあると思います。ネイティブインストーラでインストールした docker for Mac である場合には、おそらく、内部で virtualbox を動かしているのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: と、これを書いて、これはしかし「他 OS のカーネルが VM の上で再現できている理由」にはならないな、と思っている状態です。